# How can I add Unscrollable Image to a frame/Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In Tkinter Canvas how can I place a image on a canvas/Frame that has Scrollbar attached to it. But on Scrolling the scrollbar the Image shouldn't scroll, Rather the other contents like(Label) should move while scrolling making image unscrollable and below label.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do it by using new yview function for scrollbar, update position of background image as the scrollbar.

```py
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Frame, Canvas, Scrollbar, PhotoImage

def yview(action, fraction):
    canvas.yview(action, fraction)
    x, y = canvas.coords(bg)
    dy = canvas.canvasy(0)-y
    canvas.move(bg, 0, dy)

image_file = "d:/chess.png"
width, height = Image.open(image_file).size

root = Tk()

vscrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical')
vscrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y', expand=0)

canvas = Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bg='green', yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
canvas.pack(side='left', padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0)

vscrollbar.configure(command=yview)

image = PhotoImage(file=image_file)
bg = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor='nw')

# ========================  Block  ======================================
frame = Frame(canvas)
frame_id = canvas.create_window(width//2, 0, window=frame, anchor="n")

for i in range(30):
    Label(frame, text=f'Label {i+1:0>2d}', padx=5, pady=5).pack()
# ==================================================================

canvas.update()
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

[Update] frame used as container of labels will mask background image, to avoid this, need to put each widget under canvas directly.

Code for Block replaced by

```py
label_ids = []
for i in range(30):
    label = Label(canvas, text=f'Label {i+1:0>2d}', padx=5, pady=5)
    h = label.winfo_reqheight()
    label_id = canvas.create_window(width//2, int(i*(h*1.5)), window=label, anchor="n")
```

[image]

Comment: It Helped me Sir but now I also need some space(Gap) between the labels that are placed above it. While giving gaps it leaves behind some white space

Comment: It is caused by the container `frame` of all labels. Update code as above.